# Python3.6 cast string to float - bug or feature?

Tags: string, python-2.7, casting, python-3.6

I am processing strings and extracting float numbers out of them, the float numbers can be in different positions inside the strings. Then I noticed different behaviour between Python versions 2.7 and 3.6. For example, string containing non-numeric literals such as `_` 
Here is a summary of what I found:

Python 2.7:

```py
In [3]: float('0_001')
ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 0_001

In [4]:
```

Python 3.6:

```py
In [16]: float( '0_001' )
Out[16]: 1.0
```

The behaviour I would expect from the cast is inline with the 2.7 version, and since the stretch between `0_001` and `1.0` is quite wide, I suspect that this is rather a bug in the 3.6 version, but I may be wrong.

If I replace the `_` literal in version 3.6 with anything else, e.g. `- * ,` etc. I get the expected `ValueError:`.

If this is not a bug, but rather a feature, can somebody explain to me why a cast like that can be valid?

Python 2.7 version:

```
Python 2.7.16 (default, Apr  6 2019, 01:42:57) 
IPython 5.8.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
```

Python 3.6 version:

```
Python 3.6.9 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jul 30 2019, 19:07:31) 
IPython 6.2.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
```

**Edit:**
According to the answer of Sach this is actual feature of v3.6 but I still don't understand why this is? What purpose it serves?

```py
In [2]: float( '0.0_1_2_3_4' )
Out[2]: 0.01234
```

Comment: The purpose is to make larger numbers more human readable, like `1_000_000_000` see PEP 515 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/

Comment: Thanks! Thant makes sense now.
But then it surely should NOT be allowed after the decimal point? So it is a bug after all :)

Comment: `0.000_000_1` is also more readable, it's not a bug

Comment: That wraps it up, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[PEP515](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/) should contain the answer you are looking for.

> This PEP proposes to extend Python's syntax and number-from-string
>   constructors so that underscores can be used as visual separators for
>   digit grouping purposes in integral, floating-point and complex number
>   literals.
>
> This is a common feature of other modern languages, and can aid
>   readability of long literals, or literals whose value should clearly
>   separate into parts, such as bytes or words in hexadecimal notation.

It also describes rules for using them.

Answer (score 1):

From source code [1](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/floatobject.c#L208) and [2](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/pystrtod.c#L373), you can see specific handling for underscore, while converting float from string.

This is not present in 2.7 and added from 3.6

It checks for presence of underscore followed by below conditions.

1. Underscores are only allowed after digits.
2. Underscores are only allowed before digits.
3. Underscores are not allowed at the end.

Comment: Thank you! So this is a 'feature'...
However, my question is rather _why_ is underscore allowed at all, what is the purpose of it?